# Django Rest Framework - modify serializer.data

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a view where I'm doing the following -

```
def retrieve(self, request, pk=None):
    queryset = MyClass.objects.all()
    class_data = get_object_or_404(queryset, pk=pk)
    serializer = self.get_serializer(class_data)
    new_data = serializer.data.copy()
    new_data['my_field'] = 'updated info!'
    serializer = self.get_serializer(data=new_data)
    serializer.is_valid()
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

I'd like to not have to make a copy of the serializer data to update the info.  Is there a way to modify a field in a serializer before display through the view?

edit -

```
serializer.data['my_field'] = 'updated info!'
```

does not work unless I make a copy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the straightforward solution is just to set the retrieved object attribute (`class_data.my_field = 'updated info!'`).

Answer (score 0):

> In my case, I need to update the serializer.data with some exta dict.
> I solved in the following way, Merged the ordered dicts
> serializer.data[0] and the extra dict.

```
from itertools import chain
from collections import OrderedDict
class MyCreationApiView(generics.CreateAPIView):
    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        data = ...
         serializer = self.get_serializer(data=data, many=True, required=True,
                                         context={'request': self.request, 'search': search})
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        self.perform_create(serializer)
        extra_dict = {'test': []}
 return Response([OrderedDict(chain(serializer.data[0].items(), extra_dict.items()))], status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED).
```

ref: